# Metadata extraction with Apache Jackrabbit

Tags: java, content-management-system, metadata, jackrabbit, apache-tika

I was using Alfresco a little bit and there were a thin abstraction layer above Apache Tika for extracting metadata from documents.

I decided to use only Jackrabbit because I don't need such a robust solution. But except jackrabbit-text-extractors module I don't see any other support for document metadata (Dublin core properties).

More over the jackrabbit-text-extractors maven artifact version 2.0-SNAPSHOT doesn't seem to be in SVN trunk.

Could please anybody tell me what approach to choose ?

Answer (score 1):

my understanding is that jackrabbit uses tika for text extraction now

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JCR-1878